# Add to Collection if Not Null

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a very large object with many nullable-type variables. I also have a dictionary which I want to fill up with this object's non-null variables.

The code will look something like this

```
if (myObject.whatever != null)
{
myDictionary.Add("...",myObject.whatever);
}
if (myObject.somethingElse != null)
{
myDictionary.Add("...",myObject.somethingElse);

...
```

EDIT (Sorry messed up the code)

When we repeat this for the umpteenth time we get a mess of very long code. Is there some shorter way I could write this mess? I know about the Conditional Operator (aka ?) but that's just for assignments. Is there something like that for adding to a collection?

Comment: U mean that you only want to ad items that are not null

Comment: "I know about the Conditional Operator (aka ?) but that's just for assignments." Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @JohnnBlade - Yes. Each has to have a particular key in the dictionary, so i can't use reflection

Comment: _"with this object's non-null variables."_ But you're adding null values.

Comment: @hvd - Please correct me then, that's the jist of my question

Comment: If it's not a performance problem: Why not add everything and then remove what you don't need?

Comment: @Aabela It wouldn't help you here, which is why I didn't post it as an answer, but `a ? b : c` is just an expression, it can be used anywhere an expression is needed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

How about an extension method for your dictionary?

```
public static void AddIfNotNull<T,U>(this Dictionary<T,U> dic, T key, U value) 
where U : class {
    if (value != null) { dic.Add(key, value); }
}
```

You could then do this:

```
myDictionary.AddIfNotNull("...",myObject.whatever);
```

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend writing an extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void AddIfNotNull<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if ((object)value != null)
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Using `(object)value != null` ensures that this works as you'd expect with nullable types, (e.g. `int?`) value types, (e.g. `int`) and reference types (e.g. `SomeClass`).  If you compare it to `default(TValue)`, then an `int` of `0` will not be added, even though it's not null.  If you include a `TValue : class` requirement, you can't use `Nullable<T>` as the type, which it sounds like is your most common usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a method that hides your `if`:

```
AddIfNotNull(myDictionary, "...", myObject.whatever);

private static void AddIfNotNull<K,T>(
    IDictionary<K,T> myDictionary
,   K key
,   T value) {
    if (value != default(T)) {
        myDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

You can earn some "points for style" by making the method an extension (you need to add it to a static class then):

```
private static void AddIfNotNull<K,T>(
    this IDictionary<K,T> myDictionary
,   K key
,   T value) {
    if (value != default(T)) {
        myDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}

myDictionary.AddIfNotNull(myDictionary, "...", myObject.whatever);
```

If you know that you are inserting only reference type objects, replace `default(T)` with `null` and add a `class T` constraint to the generic.

Comment: Are you sure you want `AddIfNotNull<K, int>` to not add values that happen to be zero but not null? By the way, there's a missing closing parenthesis after `default(T)`.

Comment: @hvd Yes, that's a limitation. An implementation that deals both with classes and nullable values (`int?`, `double?`, etc.) is considerably more complex.

Comment: I think `if (value != null)` would be enough.

Comment: @hvd I vaguely remember having issues with that, perhaps in .NET 3.5. I needed to build a somewhat complex null checker that worked with both nullables and classes.

Comment: Null nullables box to `null`, so even if `if (value != null)` has issues (which I'd need to see), `if ((object)value != null)` would still work.

Comment: @hvd Very interesting... I just compiled it on mono with `value != null`, and it worked fine. This could have been a resharper's warning about possibly comparing a value type and `null`, I no longer remember: it was at least three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addToDict(string ?myObj, Dictionary<,> myDict) {
        if (myObj != null)
              myDict.Add("...", myObj);
}

addToDict(myObject.whatever, myDict);
addToDict(myObject.somethignElse, myDict);
```

etc